# Deserialize JSON without key

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How do I deserialize this?

```
{"bids":[[15575.35,2.44],[15567.47,2.06],[15567.07,4.68],[15563,0.11240254]],
"asks":[[16493.08,3.22487788],[16498.86,0.01864],[16550,0.0756622],[16650,0.00182419]]}
```

My code:

```
        string remoteUri = "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTCPLN/orderbook.json";
        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
        var json = myWebClient.DownloadString(remoteUri);
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var test = js.Deserialize<OrderBook>(json);


    class OrderBook
{
    public List<Order> bids { get; set; }
    public List<Order> asks { get; set; }
}

   public class Order  
{
  public Double rate { get; set; }
  public Double amount { get; set; }

}
```

I have this error:
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll

Additional information: Type 'GetValue.Class.Order' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: A Google search for "C# deserialize JSON" seems to return lots of examples using a couple of different options.  (Such as JSON.net or the `JavaScriptSerializer` built-in class.)  Have you tried anything at all?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I adde my code, I have try a lot

Comment: @Kmietek take a look at my answer it will help  you

Comment: @BRAHIM Kamel Thank You i will try it now :D

Comment: Your model is simply `public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<double>> bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> asks { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this site [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io/?l=cs&r=json2csharp), it will provide you with the following full sample

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public partial class Quote
    {
        [JsonProperty("asks")]
        public List<List<double>> Asks { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("bids")]
        public List<List<double>> Bids { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Quote
    {
        public static Quote FromJson(string json) =>
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Quote>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Quote self) =>
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
    }
}
```

to deserialize your `Json` just call

```
 var remoteUri = "https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTCPLN/orderbook.json";
 var myWebClient = new WebClient();
 var json = myWebClient.DownloadString(remoteUri);            
 var quote = Quote.FromJson(json);
```