# Deserialize JSON with nested arrays without property name C#

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have an array with following data schema

```
"coordinates" : [
      [
        [
          482035.87650000025,
          3768510.0446000006,
          0
        ],
        [
          482035.86720000021,
          3768514.4123,
          0
        ],
        [
          482035.68240000028,
          3768514.4119000006,
          0
        ]
      ]
  ]
```

What is the correct mapping class structure for Deserialize this json string into object using Newtonsoft Json

Comment: Desalinize?....

Comment: Sorry edited the title correct word is "Deserialize"

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516067/deserialize-json-without-key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd wrap that in `{ }` to make it a valid JSON object, this should be the class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<List<List<double>>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

string adjustedFragment = "{ " + json + " }";
RootObject r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(adjustedFragment);
```